# get dynamically added jButton action command

Tags: java, swing, jbutton

I have `JFrame Main` which contains in left side `JXTaskPainContainer` (content menu) and right side `cardLayout panel`. Content menu has a `JButton btn("data")`, when we click `btn` it shows on `cardLayout panel` -> `JPanel Test`. Under content menu there is `addButton`, which adds dynamic `btn` -> `"data2", "data3",...`. The layout of `Main frame` given here:

**Main frame**

```
    | jButton2 |
    -------------
    |Content menu|         CardLayout Panel
    |----------  |------------------------------------|
    |    //shows |                                    |
    |data1 ------|-> Test jPanel [Test.add(jButton1)] |
    |data2 ------|-> Test jPanel [same as above     ] |
    |data3 ------|-> Test jPanel [same as above     ] |
    |  ...       |                                    |
    |----------  |------------------------------------|
    |  AddButton |                                    |
     //data2, data3 dynamically added by AddButton
```

`jButton2` must call `Test.jButton1`:

```
private void jButton2actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
        Test.jButton1.doClick(); //here I want to call all jButton1 (i.e. data2, data3,...)
}
```

but when I click `jButton2` it calls only last clicked `Test.jButton1`. For example, if I added dynamic `data2` and `data3`, then only `jButton1` of `data3` is clicked, for `data2` is no sense.

I would like to ask how can I call all the `Test.jButton1` action commands of dynamically added `data2, data3,...` in `Main class`?

Comment: For better help sooner, post a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/).

Comment: I found where I was mistaken, but face new problem. I might create new post.

Comment: That's the way to go. If you do need to make a post, please include an MCVE/SSCCE.