# jButton click at once

Tags: java, swing, button, actionlistener

As I described before I have `Main Frame` which contains `JXTaskPainContainer`, `jPanel1` and `jButton2` and `AddButton` which adds dynamic `btn`. The layout is given [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38348994/get-dynamically-added-jbutton-action-command).

**Main class:**

```
public class Main extends javax.swing.JFrame{
public static JXTaskPaneContainer taskPaneContainer;
public static int count = 2;

public Main() {
   initComponents();

   taskPaneContainer = new JXTaskPaneContainer();
   jPanel1.setLayout(new GridLayout(1,1));
   jPanel1.add(taskPaneContainer, BorderLayout.EAST);
}

private void addMenu(String Title) {
   final JXTaskPane actionPane = new JXTaskPane();
   actionPane.setSpecial(true);
   JPanel opaquePanel = new JPanel();
   opaquePanel.setOpaque(true);
   JButton btn = new JButton("Test");
   btn.setActionCommand(Integer.toString(count));
   cardLayoutPanel.add(new Test(count), "Test"+Integer.toString(count));

   opaquePanel.add(btn);
   actionPane.add(opaquePanel);
   taskPaneContainer.add(actionPane);
}

 private void addButtonActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                            
        count++;
        addMenu("Menu " + count);
 }

private void jButton2ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
       Test.jButton1.doClick(); //call from Test panel
}
}
```

And here **Test panel**:

```
public class Test extends javax.swing.JPanel{

/**
* Creates new form Test
* @param val
*/

public Test(int val){
   initComponents();
   jButton1.setActionCommand(Integer.toString(val));
}

public Test(){        
   initComponents();
}

private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt){
   System.out.println("test"+evt.getActionCommand());
}
}
```

Now when I click `jButton2` on `Main frame` I want to call `jButton1` from `Test panel` and get their `actionCommand`. When we click `addButton` it adds dynamic `btn = new JButton("Test")` and it refers to `Test panel`. The thing what I am trying to do is add dynamic `btn`, for example if we add `btn2, btn3, btn4,` then using `jButton2` I want to `doClick()` of all `jButton1` actionCommands.

When I added this line of code in `addMenu()`:

```
Test.jButton1.setActionCommand(Integer.toString(count));
Test.jButton1.doClick();
```

Then at every click of `addButton` all of the `jButton1` of `btn2, btn3, btn4` were clicked at once. But when I want to click all `jButton1` using `jButton2` in `Main frame`:

```
private void jButton2ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
     Test.jButton1.setActionCommand(Integer.toString(count));
     Test.jButton1.doClick();
}
```

But in this case only last `jButton1` is clicked (i.e. `btn4`).
I would like to ask, how can I click all dynamically added `jButton1` of `btn2, btn3, btn4` at once using `jButton2`?
Any help is really appreciated.

Comment: 1) Use [`AbstractButton.doClick()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/AbstractButton.html#doClick--) 2) For better help sooner, post a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/).

Answer (score 0):

Use a getter rather than a static call 'Test.jButton1'

```
//include imports to make it an MCVE
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
public class Test extends javax.swing.JPanel{

    JButton jButton1;   

    public Test(int val){
        initComponents();
        jButton1.setActionCommand(Integer.toString(val));
    }

    public Test(){        
        initComponents();
    }

    private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt){
        System.out.println("test"+evt.getActionCommand());
    }

    /**
     * Add a getter, so you can get jButton1 
     */
    public JButton getjButton1() {
        return jButton1;
    }
}
```

if jPanel1 is an instance of Test you can get jButton1 by :

```
    JButton jButton1 = jPanel1.getButton1();
```

Or have it clicked by

```
jPanel1.getButton1().doClick();
```